# ESP8266/nodemcu with Arduino IDE make HTTPS REST GET Request

Tags: rest, ssl, https, get, esp8266

currently I'm working on a nodemcu/esp8266 project which connects over wifi to an accesspoint and then periodically reads (GETs) data from a custom REST service using http basic authentication and subsequentially an API key (not implemented yet).
When I'm using http, everything works fine, but when I'm trying to make the REST calls via https, I always get an error that the SSL certificate fingerprint does not match. I've extracted the fingerprint using my browser and put it into my program (I am quite familiar with using SSL certs).

I'm using dev.rest.ne-mail.net as remote REST API host (hosted by myself) and I'm using the following libraries:
https://github.com/DaKaZ/esp8266-restclient

This is how I create the REST client object:

```
RestClient client = RestClient("dev.rest.ne-mail.net", 443, "‎‎60 ED 2E 60 60 BF 2A 50 20 2B 57 B7 91 90 1A 0A 2D EC 61 33");
```

any ideas? according to ssl labs test, my server does support tls 1.2, 1.1 and various outdated (even RC4) cipher suites.

thanks!